# How to do arithmetic and or operations in prolog?

Tags: prolog

In C, given two numbers like this:

```
1010
0101
```

I can do something like this:

```
0000 == 1010&&0101;
1111 == 1010||0101;
```

Then is it possible to use Prolog do the same thing..?

Thank you!

Comment: Look here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Built-in_predicates#Other_arithmetic_and_bitwise_functors ... (Bitwise AND, Bitwise OR predicates).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In prolog, you can use the following operators for bitwise arithmatic

```
&& = /\ 
|| = \/
```

I hope this helps.